# Capturing python-background-processes output realtime

Tags: python, linux, logging, background, nohup

I have a simple long running python script which logs using `print("text to log")`. I want to run this as a background process but the output is only dumped into the specified log file when the process terminates. Is there a way to log in real time so that I can tail the logfile? I don't want to introduce unnecessary complexity in my python script; I'd rather allow the OS to handle the logging. Therefore I'm not keen in using a `Logger` class for example.

I've tried the alternatives below to no avail:

```
nohup python start.py > test.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
python start.py >> test.log 2>&1 &
```

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run Python "unbuffered", i.e.

```
python -u start.py > test.log
```

Comment: ok. Need to wait 7 more minutes until stackoverflow will allow me to